# Return Values from Table 1 based on multiple columns from table 2

Tags: sql-server, search, where-clause, multiple-columns

I want to be able to return values from Table 1 based on multiple columns from table 2.

Table 1

ID            eventDate            Price

111           2013-09-01           103

111      2013-10-04      103.5

111      2013-11-01      115

111      2013-11-02      114.5

111      2013-11-05      114

111      2013-11-09      112

112      2013-10-20      103

111      2013-10-23      103.5

111      2013-10-24      103

111      2013-10-25      103

111      2013-10-26      103

111      2013-10-27      103

etc...

Table 2 example:

ID       startDate     endDAte

111      2013-11-01    2013-11-05

112      2013-10-23    2013-11-07

113      2013-11-02    2013-11-03

114      2013-10-15    2013-11-01

115      2013-11-02    2013-11-05

I want to return results from Table 1 based on Table 2
For each row in Table 2 I want the following results from Table 1...
For ID 111, I want to know every Date and Price from Table 1 that falls between Table 2's "startDate" and "endDate". I want this information for each row of Table 2. If I only cared about one single ID I would write a simple query like...

Select ID, eventDate, Price
From Table 1
where (ID = 111) and (eventDate between startDate and endDate)

*This would get me the results I need for ID 111, but I need the same results for ID 112, 113, etc. and for each respective startDate and endDate*************

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.ID, t1.EventDate, t1.Price
  FROM dbo.Table2 AS t2
  INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 AS t1
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
  AND t1.EventDate >= t2.StartDate
  AND t1.EventDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, t2.EndDate);
```

To pre-empt questions/complaints about why I'm not using `BETWEEN` here, please read [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).